# ERROR ITMS-90596: "Invalid Bundle. The asset catalog at 'Payload/ExpoKitApp.app/.bundle/Assets.car' can't be processed."

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, itmstransporter

Problem summary : I would like to submit an app to the Apple App store (TestFlight). I am using Transporter v1.1 to submit the app. I am getting the following error in Transporter during the submission process. Please note that I am not using Xcode in this process.

Actual result:
`ERROR ITMS-90596: "Invalid Bundle. The asset catalog at 'Payload/ExpoKitApp.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCoreResources.bundle/Assets.car' can't be processed. Rebuild your app, and all included extensions and frameworks, with the latest GM version of Xcode and resubmit."`

Expected result : successful submission to the app store.

Development environment : Expo 36.0.0 / macOS High Sierra v 10.13.6 / Processor 2,3 GHz Intel Core i5 / Transporter v 1.1

What have I tried ? :

1. Deleting all node modules and installing them again (npm install).
2. Deleting any old Xcode folders on my mac. Please note that I am not using Xcode.
3. Checked the version of xcode in package-lock.json. It is 2.0.0 but it is being used as dependancy and not as a direct tool in the submission process.
4. Generate a new build thrice and submitting it once more in Transporter.

Can anyone please help me in this process ? I know this question has been asked before but the case is not applicable to me because I am not using xcode or application loader to submit the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help someone in a similar situation. Here is how I solved my problem with the advice of a senior developer.

1. Using expo diagnostics I found out the version of Xcode that my expo toolkit was using. The answer was undefined because I wasn't using Xcode at all.
2. Being on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, I needed Xcode 10.1 for compatibility.
3. I downloaded Xcode 10.1 and also the compatible command line tools.
4. I transferred the installed Xcode from the downloads folder to applications folder.
5. Again ran expo diagnostics and noted that expo has taken into account the associated Xcode version.
6. Ran expo build:ios
7. Downloaded the .ipa file generated by expo on their server.
8. Submitted the .ipa file using Transporter to the Apple app store (TestFlight).

Successful submission.

Comment: I have same problem. 
I developed app in Windows and ran `expo build:ios`.
So I don't need Xcode.
However, when submiting the app by using Transporter I got the same error ITMS-90596.
My question is why do we need to Xcode when Expo building the app for us?

Comment: That is how Apple has designed their build and submission process. I don't have a better answer for this.