# ERROR ITMS-90596: Invalid Bundle. The asset catalog at 'Payload/ExpoKitApp.app/.bundle/Assets.car' can't be processed

Tags: expo, app-store, itmstransporter

We built our app using Expo.
We published it successfully to Google Play

We got error when submitting our app to App Store. The steps that I did to submit our app:

1. `expo build:ios`
2. Wait for Expo to build our app
3. Download .ipa file on a MacBook (a very old one without XCode)
4. Submit .ipa using Transporter

I got `ERROR ITMS-90596: "Invalid Bundle. The asset catalog at 'Payload/ExpoKitApp.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCoreResources.bundle/Assets.car' can't be processed. Rebuild your app, and all included extensions and frameworks, with the latest GM version of Xcode and resubmit."` as below. (Note: image is copied from https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/195)

[image: ERROR ITMS-90596]

I think the app is build by Expo server. And it should include all required code to submit to App Stores.

What's wrong with steps above? How can we solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue (built app on windows, built IPA in cloud by Expo, failed to submit IPA on a Mac through Transporter with ITMS error code)

In this case, I submitted the IPA with **Application Loader from XCode 10.1** and it worked. I downloaded an old version here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/. I also needed to download the command line tools.

Related question: [ERROR ITMS-90596: "Invalid Bundle. The asset catalog at 'Payload/ExpoKitApp.app/.bundle/Assets.car' can't be processed."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59955693/error-itms-90596-invalid-bundle-the-asset-catalog-at-payload-expokitapp-app)